# Error Update dynamodb table on Aws in sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
        ModelName.update({token:306},{value:"unavailable"}).exec(function abc(err,daa){
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            }
            else{
                res.send(daa)
            }                   
        })
```

I have the following error:

```
Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema
    at Request.extractError (E:\Groove\Nightlife\node_modules\waterline-dynamodb\node_modules\vogels\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\protocol\json.js:43:27)
    at Request.callListeners (E:\Groove\Nightlife\node_modules\waterline-dynamodb\node_modules\vogels\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (E:\Groove\Nightlife\node_modules\waterline-dynamodb\node_modules\vogels\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (E:\Groove\Nightlife\node_modules\waterline-dynamodb\node_modules\vogels\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:596:14)
    at Request.transition (E:\Groove\Nightlife\node_modules\waterline-dynamodb\node_modules\vogels\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:21:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (E:\Groove\Nightlife\node_modules\waterline-dynamodb\node_modules\vogels\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:14:12)
    at E:\Groove\Nightlife\node_modules\waterline-dynamodb\node_modules\vogels\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (E:\Groove\Nightlife\node_modules\waterline-dynamodb\node_modules\vogels\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:37:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (E:\Groove\Nightlife\node_modules\waterline-dynamodb\node_modules\vogels\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:598:12)
    at Request.callListeners (E:\Groove\Nightlife\node_modules\waterline-dynamodb\node_modules\vogels\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:115:18)
    at Request.emit (E:\Groove\Nightlife\node_modules\waterline-dynamodb\node_modules\vogels\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (E:\Groove\Nightlife\node_modules\waterline-dynamodb\node_modules\vogels\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:596:14)
    at Request.transition (E:\Groove\Nightlife\node_modules\waterline-dynamodb\node_modules\vogels\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:21:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (E:\Groove\Nightlife\node_modules\waterline-dynamodb\node_modules\vogels\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:14:12)
    at E:\Groove\Nightlife\node_modules\waterline-dynamodb\node_modules\vogels\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (E:\Groove\Nightlife\node_modules\waterline-dynamodb\node_modules\vogels\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:37:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (E:\Groove\Nightlife\node_modules\waterline-dynamodb\node_modules\vogels\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:598:12)
    at Request.callListeners (E:\Groove\Nightlife\node_modules\waterline-dynamodb\node_modules\vogels\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:115:18)
    at callNextListener (E:\Groove\Nightlife\node_modules\waterline-dynamodb\node_modules\vogels\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:95:12)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (E:\Groove\Nightlife\node_modules\waterline-dynamodb\node_modules\vogels\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\event_listeners.js:209:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:908:16
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:381:11)
```

Details:  ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema

Comment: I Had use waterline-dynamodb module for dynamodb

Comment: Model.find() or Model.create() work properly error comes only in case Model.update()

Comment: please share it if any buddies got solution of this error